# Attribute value to new column based on values in similarly called columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, pivot-table, tidyverse

I have a data frame which has distances from a unit's centroid to different points. The points are identified by numbers and what I am trying to obtain a new column where I get the distance to the closest object.

So the data frame looks like this:

```
FID <- c(12, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18)
year <- c(1990, 1994, 1983, 1953, 1957, 2000)
centroid_distance_1 <- c(220.3, 220.3, 515.6, NA, 200.2, 22)
centroid_distance_2 <- c(520, 520, 24.3, NA , NA, 51.8)
centroid_distance_3 <- c(NA, 12.8, 124.2, NA, NA, 18.8)
centroid_distance_4 <- c(725.3, 725.3, 44.2, NA, 62.9, 217.9)
sample2 <- data.frame(FID, year, centroid_distance_1, centroid_distance_2, centroid_distance_3, centroid_distance_4)


    sample2
  FID year centroid_distance_1 centroid_distance_2 centroid_distance_3 centroid_distance_4
1  12 1990               220.3               520.0                  NA               725.3
2  12 1994               220.3               520.0                12.8               725.3
3  14 1983               515.6                24.3               124.2                44.2
4  15 1953                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
5  17 1957               200.2                  NA                  NA                62.9
6  18 2000                22.0                51.8                18.8               217.9
```

`FID` is an identifier of each unit and `year` a year indicator. Each row is a `FID`*`year` pair. `centroid_distance_x`is the row's distance between its centroid and the object `x`. This is a small sample of the data frame, which contains much more columns and rows.

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
short_distance <- c(220.3, 12.8, 24.3, NA, 62.9,18.8)
unit <- c(1, 3, 2, NA, 4, 3)
ideal.df <- data.frame(FID, year, short_distance, unit)

ideal.df
  FID year short_distance unit
1  12 1990          220.3    1
2  12 1994           12.8    3
3  14 1983           24.3    2
4  15 1953             NA   NA
5  17 1957           62.9    4
6  18 2000           18.8    3
```

Where basically, I add one column with named `short_distance` which is the cell with the lower value a row takes of all the `centroid_distance_*` columns above, and one named `unit` which identifies the object from which each row has the smaller distance (so if one row has smallest value in `centorid_distance_1` it takes the value of `1` for `unit`).

I have tried a bunch of things with `dplyr` and pivot and re-pivoting the dataframe but I'm really not getting there.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first couple of attempts at this weren't working like I imagined, either - couldn't always get the NA behavior you want - but here's one that works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2) # Or use tidyr if you prefer


sample2 %>%
    # Melt/unpivot to one value per row
    melt(id.vars = c("FID", "year")) %>%
    # Extract the unit number
    mutate(
        unit = sub(x = variable,
                   pattern = "^centroid_distance_",
                   replacement = "")
    ) %>%
    group_by(FID, year) %>% # Group by FID and year to get one row of output for each
    arrange(value) %>%      # Put smallest distance at the top of each group
    slice_head(n = 1)       # Take one row from the top of each group
```

Comment: `slice_min` from `dplyr` didn't work for me here, because it dropped the group with all-NA values.

Comment: Aha! rjen's answer shows that setting `with_ties = FALSE` allows the all-NA rows to come through. So you could replace the `arrange` and `slice_head` steps here with `slice_min(value, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE)`, as they posted.

Comment: That didn't really work well with the NAs, but your original answer did. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution based in the tidyverse - using `pivot_longer` - could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

sample2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(FID, year)) %>%
  group_by(year, FID) %>%
  slice_min(value, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(unit = str_sub(name, -1)) %>%
  select(-name, short_distance = value)

# Groups:   year, FID [6]
#     FID  year short_distance unit 
#   <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>
# 1    15  1953           NA   1    
# 2    17  1957           62.9 4    
# 3    14  1983           24.3 2    
# 4    12  1990          220.  1    
# 5    12  1994           12.8 3    
# 6    18  2000           18.8 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using dplyr & stringr packages (but you can just import tidyverse):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- sample2 %>% 
  gather('centroid', 'dist', 3:length(.)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  slice(if(all(is.na(dist))) 1L else which.min(dist)) %>%
  mutate(centroid = str_replace(centroid, "centroid_distance_", ""))

df
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   year [6]
    FID  year centroid  dist
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1    15  1953 1         NA  
2    17  1957 4         62.9
3    14  1983 2         24.3
4    12  1990 1        220. 
5    12  1994 3         12.8
6    18  2000 3         18.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution

```r
FID <- c(12, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18)
year <- c(1990, 1994, 1983, 1953, 1957, 2000)
centroid_distance_1 <- c(220.3, 220.3, 515.6, NA, 200.2, 22)
centroid_distance_2 <- c(520, 520, 24.3, NA , NA, 51.8)
centroid_distance_3 <- c(NA, 12.8, 124.2, NA, NA, 18.8)
centroid_distance_4 <- c(725.3, 725.3, 44.2, NA, 62.9, 217.9)
sample2 <- data.frame(FID, year, centroid_distance_1, centroid_distance_2, centroid_distance_3, centroid_distance_4)
```

Apply function `min` for each row and add it to the data frame as column `short_distance`. Ignore the warning and handle it in the next operation.

```r
sample2$short_distance <- apply(sample2[,3:6], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
#> Warning in FUN(newX[, i], ...): kein nicht-fehlendes Argument für min; gebe Inf
#> zurück
sample2$short_distance[is.infinite(sample2$short_distance)] <- NA #C hange `Inf` created by the `min` function to to `NA`
```

Get units with `which.min`. `ifelse` is required because `min.which` would drop `NA` rows.

```r
sample2$unit <- apply(sample2[,3:6], 1, function(x) ifelse(length(which.min(x)) == 0, NA, which.min(x)))
```

Keep only relevant columns

```r
sample2 <- sample2[, c(1,2,7,8)]
sample2
#>   FID year short_distance unit
#> 1  12 1990          220.3    1
#> 2  12 1994           12.8    3
#> 3  14 1983           24.3    2
#> 4  15 1953             NA   NA
#> 5  17 1957           62.9    4
#> 6  18 2000           18.8    3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A data.table solution

```
setDT(sample2)
s <- melt(sample2, id = 1:2, variable.name = "object", value.name = "distance")   ## pivot
s[, obj := as.numeric(object)    ## transform factor into numeric
  ][, .(shortest = min(distance, na.rm=TRUE), unit= which.min(distance)), by = .(FID, year)   ## calculate the shortest and which
    ][is.infinite(shortest), shortest:= NA   # transform Inf into NA  
      ][]  ## report
```